# Tomcat access logs - are failed requests included?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat, java

We have a RESTful web service (Java, hosted in Tomcat on Ubuntu on Amazon EC2). From time to time it fails (not every week). When it fails, Java CPU consumption goes to 100% and it takes all available memory. It does not finish by itself. I have to restart the server.

There is nothing suspicious in Tomcat access logs.
I guess one of our users could submit a very "heavy" request which brought the server down.
Is it possible this request is not in Tomcat logs since it never finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat logs the end-time of the request in the access log so only completed requests are logged. We had a similar issue and a similar suspicion. Using WireShark we monitored all traffic and discovered the requests which caused our problem.

A better idea would be to put an Apache Server in front of tomcat and log there, alternatively a load balance could perform the same function.