# Tomcat localhost access log does not contain failed requests

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, logging, tomcat

Default Tomcat 8.5 logs do not appear to show any failed requests, or anything about the SSL handshakes. Specifically the localhost log and catalina.out

See this question for context about the type of failed request:
[Intermittent Curl 35 error when using self signed certificate on Tomcat](https://serverfault.com/questions/999699/intermittent-curl-35-error-when-using-self-signed-certificate-on-tomcat)

This question seems to indicate that it is not possible....?
[Tomcat access logs - are failed requests included?](https://serverfault.com/questions/518683/tomcat-access-logs-are-failed-requests-included)

I tried turning on debug, but still couldn't find anything related to a failed request.

Comment: Are you checking all logs? The `localhost_access.log` should contain the `500` errors. Application specific logs may end up in `localhost.<current_date>.log` or in application specific logs.

Comment: It's not actually a 500 server error, it doesn't seem to get that far. There is effectively no response from the server. As if it's failing during the SSL handshake. I'm using Tomcat with APR for SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log the connection details, you need to increase to log levels of loggers `org.apache.coyote` and `org.apache.tomcat.util.net`, by putting:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.level = FINE
org.apache.coyote.level = FINE
```

in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties` and increasing the log level of some handler, e.g.:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
```

whose messages eventually end up in `catalina.out`.

This requires a server restart. You should be able to do the same thing through JMX (e.g. **jconsole**), without a restart.

Comment: I just had to set org.apache.coyote.http2.level to FINE and that gave me a stack of output. Not sure if it's exactly the one I'm looking for yet. But there is an EOF Exception in there, so good place to start.