# Tomcat RequestProcessor errorCount - what counts as an error?

Tags: monitoring, tomcat, tomcat7

We have a Zabbix server that reports on Tomcat's errorCount, from the GlobalRequestProcessor. I'm trying to figure out exactly what gets counted in this errorCount. Is it *any* request to Tomcat the results in an error? If so, how are these measured? Any request that results in an HTTP error response code (4xx/5xx)? Are there other conditions that *would* also affect errorCount that would *not* affect the HTTP response code?

Basically, if someone sees a chart showing that the error rate is increasing, what should they look at to see where the errors are coming from: Application logs? Tomcat logs? Apache web logs? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct: as the comment in the `org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo` class says:

```
// number of response codes >= 400
private int errorCount;
```

the `errorCount` is incremented for each request that results in a `4xx/5xx` status code and nothing more. SSL handshake errors will not get counted, as reported in [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/999715/530633), since they don't create a request.

The `4xx/5xx` errors will certainly leave a trace in the access log (`localhost_access.log` in the default config) and if the error was caused by an exception, it will probably find its way to `catalina.<date>.log`.

I don't know, which role plays Apache2 in your installation, but if it serves as reverse proxy it will mirror Tomcat's access log with some errors of its own.